# Store Application [Graph Data base or SQL ]

Tags: sql, neo4j

I have  a question I want  to make an application for a store which stores, show information about items , receipts , vendors, clients, profits

what is the best technology to use in this case SQL or neo4j for example ? and why :) ?

Thank you so much your help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j is a graph database. So, performance wise, its always better than relational database. You just need to model your requirement considering the neo4j features. Recently, I have read a blog pointing the performance difference between graph database and relational database.
Read this [Why Graph database? Why Neo4j?](http://muhammadhamed.blogspot.com/2012/05/why-graph-database-why-neo4j.html)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your usage scenarios. Do you simply want to store inventory and customer information? Do you want to mine data from transactions, like who bought what? Do you want to implement a recommender system?

Generally, when having lots of interrelated data and you're primarily interested in these relations, using a graph database is a good choice. In most other cases, it isn't. That doesn't mean that NoSQL is from the table, though: If your items' stored information greatly differs in structure, using a schema-less database (e.g. a document store like CouchDB or MongoDB) might still be a good idea.

If you're simply interested in storing your data, SQL is a good choice. If you like to aggregate over this data (e.g. to check inventories, analyse sales, etc.) it might even be the best one.

PS: It is wrong to assume that a graph database is always faster than a relational database. That totally depends on your data model and the kind of queries you need to do.

Regards
 Hendrik